# select column name from max query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query that goes something like this :

```
 ;WITH t as
(
select 1 as RowNumber, 1 as ObjectID, 10 as [Col1],  20 as [Col2],  20 as [Col3],  20 as [Col4] UNION ALL
select 2 as RowNumber, 2 as ObjectID, 20 as [Col1],  30 as [Col2],  40 as [Col3],  50 as [Col4]
)
SELECT  RowNumber, ObjectID,
        (
        SELECT  MAX(Amount)
        FROM    (
                SELECT  [Col1] AS Amount
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  [Col2]
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  [Col3]
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  [Col4]
                ) d
       WHERE   Amount > 0
        )
FROM    t
```

The query works fine, but I want to know is where the Max(Amount) comes from.

So in my result set, on top of having (RowNumber, ObjectId, Amount) I want the name of the column (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4) as a String.

Is there any way to do that?

**EDIT**
Question from the comments : If two columns have the same max, it could be either one? Yes, it could be either one. Any column name will do as long as I know where it could be coming from.

Using SQL Server 2008

Comment: What if both Col1 and Col2 have the same MAX: it could be either one...?

Comment: Hope you don't mind I've just edited your code to make it a runnable example as I had never seen that approach before. Feel free to roll it back!

Comment: @Martin : I'm fine with the edit. Makes it easier for people to answer. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [UNPIVOT](http://syntaxhelp.com/SQLServer/UNPIVOT) and [OUTER APPLY](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1958):

```
;WITH t as     (
select 1 as RowNumber, 1 as ObjectID, 10 as [Col1],  20 as [Col2],  
       20 as [Col3],  20 as [Col4] UNION ALL
select 2 as RowNumber, 2 as ObjectID, 20 as [Col1],  30 as [Col2],  
       40 as [Col3],  50 as [Col4] )
SELECT 
  RowNumber,
  ObjectID,
  ColName,
  ColAmount
FROM t
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 
    ColName,
    ColAmount
  FROM 
    (
      SELECT
        Col1,
        Col2,
        Col3,
        Col4
    ) x 
    UNPIVOT (
      ColAmount FOR ColName IN (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4) 
    ) y
   WHERE ColAmount > 0
   ORDER BY ColAmount DESC
 ) z
```

Results:

```
RowNumber   ObjectID    ColName   ColAmount
----------- ----------- --------- -----------
1           1           Col2      20
2           2           Col4      50
```

Comment: Thanks, this turned out to be the best solution here. Didn't know about the UNPIVOT function but it's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Don't MAX: use TOP which avoids the aggregate/GROUP BY.

It can also deal with duplicates using WITH TIES

I'm not sure if what you had was psuedo-code or a sub-query, but this should do what you want

```
 SELECT TOP 1 -- WITH TIES if needed
     *
 FROM
     (
     SELECT  RowNumber, ObjectID, [Col1] AS Amount, 'Col1' AS ColName
     FROM table
     UNION ALL
     SELECT  RowNumber, ObjectID, [Col2], 'Col2' AS ColName
     FROM table
     UNION ALL
     SELECT  RowNumber, ObjectID, [Col3], 'Col3' AS ColName
     FROM table
     UNION ALL
     SELECT  RowNumber, ObjectID, [Col4], 'Col4' AS ColName
     FROM table
     ) foo
 WHERE   Amount > 0
 ORDER BY Amount DESC
```

Your main problem is that you'll have to touch the table 4 times no matter how you do it because a subquery only returns one value. I can't see a ROW_NUMBER solution either (but there probably is one though... :-)

Comment: His query was doing it per row. I never knew you could do that.

Comment: @Martin Smith: It works, but I'm not sure how to get columnname too because it's subquery which allows one value only. See these links: http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2006/05/08/Neat-trick-to-find-max-value-of-multiple-columns.aspx or http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2006/05/16/Performance-of-MAX-trick.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is a sub-query, the full query is longer than that and has more than 4 columns that I could be getting the name of. This query will not be running over and over, so i'm not worried about efficiency. I just want accurate results. Will try your solution in the full query and mark as accepted if I can get it to work like that.

Comment: +1. I've never seen this type of referencing of columns either.

Answer (score 4):

This is untested: however to see whats going on with your data, this might help. Not really production code quality:

```
SELECT  RowNumber, ObjectID,
        (
        SELECT  MAX(Amount)
        FROM    (
                SELECT str([Col1]) + ", col1, " AS Amount
                UNION ALL
                SELECT str([Col2]) + ", col2" 
                UNION ALL
                SELECT str([Col3]) + ", col3"
                UNION ALL
                SELECT str([Col4]) + ", col4"
                )
        WHERE   Amount > 0
        )
FROM    table
```

str() is the  "toString()" function of your DBMS.
Your SQL seems pretty weird, what DBMS are you using?

Comment: You'd have to have `Amount > '0'` but this is quite neat + 1

Comment: That's a clever way of doing it. Didn't think about appending the column name as a String like that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Adding a step to [user202553's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842631/select-column-name-from-max-query/3842767#3842767)

```
;WITH t1 as(
select 1 as RowNumber, 1 as ObjectID, 10 as [Col1],  20 as [Col2],  20 as [Col3],  20 as [Col4] UNION ALL
select 2 as RowNumber, 2 as ObjectID, 20 as [Col1],  30 as [Col2],  40 as [Col3],  50000045 as [Col4]
),
t2 as(
SELECT  RowNumber, ObjectID,
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 CAST(C AS BINARY(4)) + CAST(Amount as BINARY(4)) 
        FROM    (
                SELECT 'Col1' AS C, [Col1] AS Amount
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'Col2' AS C, [Col2]
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'Col3' AS C, [Col3]
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'Col4' AS C, [Col4]
                ) d
       WHERE   Amount > 0
       ORDER BY Amount desc
        ) AS Top1
FROM    t1
)
SELECT RowNumber, 
       ObjectID,
       CAST(Left(Top1, 4) AS CHAR(4)) AS Col, 
       CAST(SUBSTRING(Top1,5,4) AS INT) AS Amount
FROM t2
```

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty clean as well

Comment: Even neater then string concat: fixed length "encoding"